# Diplay detailed Error pages for specific users only

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, custom-errors

I'm using IIS 7.5 Webserver.

Is it possible to show the detailed Error to some special users and to any other user a CustomErrorPage?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on server or site level, or any IIS level. You can only do that for error pages within your own application.